# Can service be part of a angular2 feature module?

Tags: angular

I have a feature module with few components and accompanying service. How can I bundle service into feature module so that it can be imported into `app.module.ts` with:

`import { WorkerModule, WorkerService } from './worker/worker.module';`

Comment: Yes, you can have a service in a feature module. Why do you need to expose it in the app module? Shouldn't in then be in a shared module.

Comment: I think that all elements (components, interfaces, services etc.) for a worker feature should be in WorkerModule. I would like to expose WorkerService in app module so other feature modules could use is as a singleton. Shared module will contain only generic and non-specific elements. Am I on a wrong track?